# Is the Function in the GROUP BY Clause Necessary?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12.1

I'm an Oracle newbie just trying to learn.

Are the following two queries equivalent in terms of their results?

### Query 1

```
SELECT
    COUNT( customers.id ) AS "id",
    customers.full_name AS "name",
    customers.cty AS "country",
    TO_CHAR( customers.date, 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) AS "date"

FROM customers

GROUP BY
    customers.full_name,
    customers.cty,
    TO_CHAR( customers.date, 'mm/dd/yyyy' );
```

### Query 2: No TO_CHAR() in the GROUP BY Clause

```
SELECT
    COUNT( customers.id ) AS "id",
    customers.full_name AS "name",
    customers.cty AS "country",
    TO_CHAR( customers.date, 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) AS "date"

FROM customers

GROUP BY
    customers.full_name,
    customers.cty,
    customers.date;
```

I'm using Oracle version 12.1.

Comment: TO_CHAR` is not an aggregate function, and all columns that are in the SELECT list that are not aggregated need to be in the GROUP BY. However, in your first one you've not included `customers.city` in the GROUP BY, so it's still wrong. The second is also missing the same column. Why couldn't you test this yourself?

Comment: Moreover, `date` cannot be used unquoted like in `customes.date` as been a reserved keyword.

Comment: @KenWhite, I did include customers.cty in first one's GROUP BY clause. I can't test it myself because I don't have access to the system right now.

Comment: @KenWhite city? Why should it be there? and re "TO_CHAR` is not an aggregate function" - I don't see it was mentioned as an aggregate one...

Comment: @GTSJoe They are not equal, as date columns can contain time (hours,minutes,seconds), so when you aggregate by `to_char(..., 'mm/dd/yyyy' )`, you lose the time part

Comment: aggregating by `to_char(date_col, 'mm/dd/yyyy' )` is similar to aggregating by `truncate(date_col, 'dd')`, not to `date_col`

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov But it does it make a difference in the result set if I omit TO_CHAR() or does it return the same thing?

Comment: _"But it does it make a difference in the result set if I omit TO_CHAR()"_   TO_CHAR  returns a character string.   We presume that customers.date column is a DATE data type, which is a _binary_ structure, not a character string.  So . . .  TO_CHAR(somedate) does not equal somedate.   As for _" I don't have access to the system right now"_  why don't you have your own personal system for learning/testing?  See [Private oracle test lab](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/create-a-private-oracle-test-lab-for-free/)

Comment: You don't even need your own database, when there are sites like  https://livesql.oracle.com, https://dbfiddle.uk and http://sqlfiddle.com where you can test queries instantly and share the link.

Comment: Simple example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9358bde67c33080a1486c701c1d0b8de

Comment: "I'm using Oracle version 12.1" Normally I would recommend upgrading as this is out of support. There are several 12.1 bugs that are relevant to group by when dealing with expressions in the `select` clause, so even more reason to upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries won't return the same result... unless `customers.date` includes only dates with no time part. The `DATE` type in Oracle includes the date part and also the time part. So it's equivalent to a time stamp.

The first query groups by whole days, while the second one groups by date/hour/minute/second.

Comment: In a nutshell, this was the answer I was looking for, that in fact, the queries WON'T return the same result. There IS a difference. I SHOULD indeed stick to using Query 1. A special thanks to all those that suggested testing the code myself. I created an Oracle account and tested the queries using their "Oracle Live SQL" playground. Thanks to all who posted, this Oracle newbie appreciates it and will continue learning! 

Answer (score -3):

No. I don't even think the second one will run since your GROUP BY doesn't match your SELECT (excluding the aggregate fields such as COUNT(*)

Comment: If you group by date column, you *can* format it using to_char in the select-list, see the second query here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9358bde67c33080a1486c701c1d0b8de

Comment: If you group by the base column but use a function in the `select` list, the function is applied to the aggregated results, i.e. once per group, which can make a significant difference to performance, especially if using a user-defined function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).